# Why does this bake produce different results than the unbaked model?

Tags: materials, texture-baking

I am trying to bake a procedural map (diffuse only) and the result is not the same as generated by the procedural map. the procedural map is the first image below. the second image is the bake of this procedural map.

is there any specific setting to make this bake look like this procedural map? like ?
I want to bake only the diffuse channel.

[image]

thanks

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: after editing the locked question what do i do to unlock ? thanks

Comment: Editing is enough, it will automatically put it up on queue for review, so it can be reopened, or we can recommend further edits if needed. You can also tag it for reopening or flag for moderator if need be